# Having issues setting up an if-else statement to remove specific currency and keep it updated

Tags: c++

ive never posted on here before until now and i have spent hours pulling my hair out because i cant seem to find a method of removing currency and outputting it on my final report.

```
int main(){
    int quart = 25, nickle = 5, dime = 10; //assign coin value
    int numOfQ, numOfN, numOfD; //total numbers of each type of coin
    cout << "Fill up the machin with change. Please wait. . .";
    cout << "\nEnter number of quarters, dimes, and nickles --> ";
    cin >> numOfQ >> numOfD >> numOfN;
    cout << "\nThere are " << numOfQ << " quarters, " << numOfD << "           dimes, " << "and " << numOfN << " nickles.";

    //create balance for user to know how much money is in machine
    int total = (numOfQ * quart) + (numOfD * dime) + (numOfN * nickle);
    float balance = static_cast<float>(total) / 100.0;

    //display info
    cout << "\nThe initial balance is $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << balance <<".";
    cout << "\nOnly one-dollar bills will be accepted.\nOnly amounts between 0 and 100 and multiples of 5 will be accepted.";
    cout << "\nEnter 0 to stop the program.\nMachine is now ready.";
    cout << "\n\nPlease enter the price of the item of interest: ";

    //when losing money from machine:
    int itemPrice;
    int numOfDollars;

    while (cin >> itemPrice){
        if (itemPrice < 0) {
            cout << "Not a valid item price. Item must be greater than 0. Please try again.";
            cout << "\n\nEnter a purchase amount: ";
        }
        else if (itemPrice % 5 != 0){
            cout << "Not a valid item price. Item must be a multiple of 5. Please try again.";
            cout << "\n\nEnter a purchase amount: ";
        }
        else if (itemPrice > 100){
            cout << "Not a valid item price. Item must be less than or equal to 100. Please try again.";
            cout << "\n\nEnter a purchase amount: ";
        }
        else if (itemPrice == 0){
            int total = (numOfQ * quart) + (numOfD * dime) + (numOfN * nickle); //reinistialize total for final output
            cout << "Final Report is being generated. . .";
            cout << "\nNumber of dollars: " << setw(3) << numOfDollars;
            cout << "\nNumber of quarters: " << setw(2) << numOfQ;
            cout << "\nNumber of dimes: "  << setw(5) << numOfD;
            cout << "\nNumber of nickles: " << setw(3) << numOfN;
            cout << "\nMachine balance: " << setw(5)<< "$" << static_cast<float>(total) / 100 + numOfDollars;
            cout << "\nMachine is shutting down. Goodbye.";
            break;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Your purchase amount is: " << itemPrice << " cents.";
            cout << "\nPlease insert one-dollar bill.\nProcessing your purchase. . .";
            int change = 100 - itemPrice; //needs to be placed here not at the top of main
            int qLost = change / quart;
            int remainder = change % quart;
            int dLost = remainder / dime;
            int remainder2 = remainder % dime;
            int nLost = remainder2 /nickle;
            numOfDollars++;
            numOfQ -= qLost;
            numOfD -= dLost;
            numOfN -= nLost;

            cout << "\nYour change of " << change << " cents is given as:" << endl;
            cout << "quarter(s): " << setw(2) << qLost << endl;
            cout << "dime(s): " << setw(5) << dLost << endl;
            cout << "nickle(s): " << setw(3) << nLost << endl;
            cout << "\nEnter a purchase amount: ";
        }


}
```

In the final report, i get negative values for the quarters and so on... i know theres a missing condition but EVERY time i place a statement above or below my assigned variables the entire code breaks... please help

Comment: Fill up the machin with change. Please wait. . .
Enter number of quarters, dimes, and nickles --> 2 4 4

Enter a purchase amount: 35
Your purchase amount is: 35 cents.
Please insert one-dollar bill.
Processing your purchase. . .
Your change of 65 cents is given as:
quarter(s):  2
dime(s):     1
nickle(s):   1

Enter a purchase amount: 0
Final Report is being generated. . .
Number of dollars:   2
Number of quarters: -2
Number of dimes:     2
Number of nickles:   2
Machine balance:     $1.80

Comment: Are you making sure you aren't emptying more quarters than you have? Step through it with a debugger.

Comment: In Visual Studio there is a thing called step into(F11) inside debug menu, make use of it!

Comment: thanks for the advice ill definitely try it out right now

Comment: So i actually just solved one part of the problem. I created a seperate if statement so the machine output the right amount of coins. Now i just need to ensure that IF the machine has no more coins to give it will output a message to deny transaction!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. My conditions were placed wrong. In case anyone wants to better understand. I removed the final else condition and made it into a separate if-else statement so the compiler wouldn't get confused.

By creating a separate if statement and creating a new algorithim, it sorted the coins in order from Q -> D -> N.

afterwards i tacked on the starting if statement to verify if there were enough coins to begin with to make sure that IF NOT, the loop would end and ask for used input again. Posting the code below!

```
if (qLost > numOfQ && dLost > numOfD){
        cout << "No money. Peace.";
        cout << "\n\nEnter a purchase amount: ";
        qLost = 0;
        dLost = 0;
        nLost = 0;
    }
else if (numOfQ == 0) {
        cout << "Your purchase amount is: " << itemPrice << " cents.";
        cout << "\nPlease insert one-dollar bill.\nProcessing your purchase. . .";
        int change = 100 - itemPrice; //needs to be placed here not at the top of main
        int qLost = 0;
        int dLost = change / dime;
        int remainder = change % dime;
        int nLost = remainder /nickle;
        numOfDollars++;
        numOfQ -= qLost;
        numOfD -= dLost;
        numOfN -= nLost;

        cout << "\nYour change of " << change << " cents is given as:" << endl;
        cout << "quarter(s): " << setw(2) << qLost << endl;
        cout << "dime(s): " << setw(5) << dLost << endl;
        cout << "nickle(s): " << setw(3) << nLost << endl;
        cout << "\nEnter a purchase amount: ";
    }
    else if (numOfQ == 0 && numOfD == 0){
        cout << "Your purchase amount is: " << itemPrice << " cents.";
        cout << "\nPlease insert one-dollar bill.\nProcessing your purchase. . .";
        int change = 100 - itemPrice; //needs to be placed here not at the top of main
        int qLost = 0;
        int dLost = 0;
        int nLost = change /nickle;
        numOfDollars++;
        numOfQ -= qLost;
        numOfD -= dLost;
        numOfN -= nLost;

        cout << "\nYour change of " << change << " cents is given as:" << endl;
        cout << "quarter(s): " << setw(2) << qLost << endl;
        cout << "dime(s): " << setw(5) << dLost << endl;
        cout << "nickle(s): " << setw(3) << nLost << endl;
        cout << "\nEnter a purchase amount: ";
    }
    else if (numOfQ == 0 && numOfD == 0 && numOfN == 0){
        cout << "Not enough coins.";
    }
    else{
        cout << "Your purchase amount is: " << itemPrice << " cents.";
        cout << "\nPlease insert one-dollar bill.\nProcessing your purchase. . .";
        int change = 100 - itemPrice; //needs to be placed here not at the top of main
        int qLost = change / quart;
        int remainder = change % quart;
        int dLost = remainder / dime;
        int remainder2 = remainder % dime;
        int nLost = remainder2 /nickle;
        numOfDollars++;
        numOfQ -= qLost;
        numOfD -= dLost;
        numOfN -= nLost;

        cout << "\nYour change of " << change << " cents is given as:" << endl;
        cout << "quarter(s): " << setw(2) << qLost << endl;
        cout << "dime(s): " << setw(5) << dLost << endl;
        cout << "nickle(s): " << setw(3) << nLost << endl;
        cout << "\nEnter a purchase amount: ";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually problem here is with your input method.

You enter "35\n" as input (by pressing Return after inputting value). `cin>>itemPrice` reads `35` and performs calculation and then it can still read `\n` which is `10` in value. So it doesn't get skipped with your `itemPrice % 5 != 0` condition.

Simplest solution to this would be to add `getchar()` and `fflush()` at the end of your loop to make sure that all input is removed before proceeding. This can however generate further problems. Much better solution would be to remove `cin>>itemPrice` as loop condition and use `getline()` and extract integer from that line.

Comment: the itemPrice % 5 condition outputs only a statement that says the user input itemPrice is invalid so thats not the problem... thanks for the help though!